# Buddy Press query displayed user posts

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

in a custom user tab I'm trying to display posts by that user. (displayed user, not logged in user).

I found this code on a forum but it's not working for me. It should pull the 'displayed users' posts only, instead it shows all posts.

```
<?php 
global $bp; 
query_posts( 'author=' . $bp->displayed_user->id ); if (have_posts()) :
```

?>

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and thank you with your piece of code, it works for me now :) I have the other piece of the puzzle : find bp_core_functions.php in your buddypress plugin folder, and add this :

```
function bp_dump() {
    global $bp;

    foreach ( (array)$bp as $key => $value ) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo '<strong>' . $key . ': </strong><br />';
        print_r( $value );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    die;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'bp_dump' );
```

That's all.